# Can not even uninstall Anaconda because it can not solve the environment

Tags: anaconda, conda

I'm trying to uninstall and then install conda to see if this can solve my "The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully" problem.

I tried to use the command  conda update --all but failed. I then decided to try conda install anaconda-clean, but this also give me the inconsistent enviroment error problem. Are there any other options for me to go?

Thank you all in advance!